# Layout pass for flex box with flex-direction set to column

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to understand how CSS assigns space when the flex-direction for a div is set to column.

My basic layout & goals:

- Root div (fixed width, flex-direction: column)

  - Left div (fixed width)
  - Right div (take remaining width, flex-direction: row)

    - Child div 1
    - Child div 2
    - Child div 3 (some long text that I want to truncate)

I cannot get `Child div 3` to respect the size restriction I want to place on `Right div`. If `Child div 3` does not exist, `Right div` appears to behave as I want it to. But as soon as one of its children asks for more space, it happily stretches beyond its bounds.

I'd love to understand how I can tell `Right div` to strictly take the space left and not stretch beyond that, limiting its children as if I had set `width: <N>px` on it.

I've simplified my layout and sample to illustrate the problem.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .root {
      background-color: #c3c3c3;
    }
    
    .content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      width: 400px;
      padding: 12px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: #00ff0030;
    }
    
    .left {
      flex-grow: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      width: 160px;
      height: 160px;
      padding: 8px;
      background-color: #ff00ff30;
      color: white;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    .right {
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: #0000ff30;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    .right > :not(:first-child) {
      margin-top: 8px;
    }
    
    .right > div {
      background-color: #ffffff30;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      word-break: break-all;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="root">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="left">Left</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div>Test 1</div>
          <div>Test 2</div>
          <div>Test 3</div>
          <div>Really long text 123 Really long text 123 Really long text 123 Really long text 123</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: min-widh:0 to right element + remove flex-shrink:0

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif! I didn't know which keywords to search for. The linked question totally answers my query.